# NLP or Antlr to Manipulate Home-grown Spec Language

Tags: nlp, antlr, stanford-nlp

Looking for suggestion or ideas on best way to procede
Was trying to develop a way for Analyst to develop a Spec doc that describes the possible STATES that our
Process(BlackBoc) generates that can
then feed other process like Documentation generation(Flowcharts etc) , Testing, Code Generation etc

If the Spec was written in a Programming Coding type Language Syntax then manipulated with NLP or ANTLR
to create a List of POssible States that our Process(BlackBoc) generates

I gues my questions are
1)Has anyone done anything like this ?
2)Would ANTLR or NLP be best way to procede to maniulate a document written in Programming Coding type Language??

Thanks

**LIST of States from Spec Language - that could feed other processes**

```
"CAR" : CAR_FULLSIZE_CHASSIS  :  350cc : CAR = 1X23 (Altima SE)
"CAR" : CAR = 1X23 (Altima S)
```

or maybe

```
VEHICLE = "CAR" = True : CHASSIS = CAR_FULLSIZE_CHASSIS = True  : CAR_ENGIN_SIZE > 350cc = True : CAR = 1X23 (Altima SE)
VEHICLE = "CAR" = True : CHASSIS = CAR_FULLSIZE_CHASSIS = False: CAR_ENGIN_SIZE > 350cc = False : CAR = 1X23 (Altima S)
```

**Spec Language written by Analyst**

```
if VEHICLE = "CAR"
if CHASSIS IN LIST ( CAR_FULLSIZE_CHASSIS )
    if CAR_ENGIN_SIZE > 350cc
        CAR = 1X23 (Altima SE)
    else
        CAR = 1X24 (Altima S)
else
    ....
```

Comment: This is clearly not an NLP problem. Do you see natural language anywhere in there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I gues my questions are
>
> 1)Has anyone done anything like this ?
>
> 2)Would ANTLR or NLP be best way to procede to maniulate a document written in Programming Coding type Language?

1. yes;
2. as mentioned in the comments already: this is not a job for an NLP parser. An NLP parser is suitable for parsing natural languages, as the name suggests. The example snippet of the language you posted might have ambiguities, but looks structured enough to describe through a grammar and let some parser generator (like ANTLR) generate a parser for you.

Comment: Thanks - Do you know of anything online where people describe there experiences with #1 ???